# How can I output the content of the page using this code?

Tags: the-content

I found this code on stackoverflow, but how do I output the actual content rather than just that ID line in the example!

```
<?php
        $the_slug = 'my-page';
        $args=array(
        'name' => $the_slug,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => 1
        );
        $my_posts = get_posts($args);
        if( $my_posts ) {
            echo 'ID on the first post found '.$my_posts[0]->ID; the_content();
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($my_posts)`. There you will find what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "custom" loop outside of the main WordPress query (`query_posts`), you will have to tell WordPress to setup the post data using `setup_postdata()`

More info on `get_posts()` is found here, giving you basically what I am about to write below: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Tip: The WordPress Codex is the best friend you will ever have, apart from Google.

```
<?php

$the_slug = 'my-page';

$args = array(
    'name'          => $the_slug,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'numberposts'   => 1
);

$my_posts = get_posts($args);

if( $my_posts ) {

    echo 'ID on the first post found '.$my_posts[0]->ID;

    // To get the content of the first post:
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $my_posts[0]->post_content);

    // if you now wanted to remove the first post from this loop and assign it to a different variable $first_post
    // However, it looks as if you are only grabbing one "post" being a "page" from the slug "my-page"
    $first_post = $my_posts[0];
    unset($my_posts[0]);

    foreach($my_posts as $p): setup_postdata($p); 

        // Now you can use the_title(), the_content() etc as you normally would

    endforeach;

}

// Reset WordPress Loop & WP_Query
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: The main query is using `WP_Query`

Answer (score 0):

`$my_posts[0]->post_content`

for proper look you'll need to apply filter `the_content` and do some replace ( like `the_content()` does )

`str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', apply_filters('the_content', $my_posts[0]->post_content ) );`

if your going to use it a lot i suggest u make your own function:

`function my_get_content( $content ) { return  str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', apply_filters('the_content', $content ) );`

and then call it like so: `echo my_get_content( $my_posts[0]->post_content );`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As the chap above demonstrated, you can actually do it with this code: echo apply_filters('the_content', $my_posts[0]->post_content);